# jQuery can't find options appended to list

Tags: jquery, html

I have two lists, one has regions and the other has Postal Codes.  When I select a region from one list, I want the correct postalCodes to be highlighted in the other list.  I have to add the postalCodes dynamically when I load the page.  The postalCodes get added and display just fine, but I can't find the correct postalCode with jQuery, so I decided to dump my postalList to the console to see what it looks like.  The output shows that the options are empty "0{}1{}2{}3{}4{}5{}".

Take a look at my function.

```
function GetPostal() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: api_url + 'home/Area/GetPostal', 
    success: function(_d) {
        $.each(_d, function(postal) {
            $('select[name="postalList"]').append($('<option/>', {
                value: _d[postal].Id,
                text: _d[postal].Name
            }));
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify($('select[name="postalList"]')));
    }
}).fail(function(_d) {
    //Handle error
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$('select[name="postalList"]')` you try to stringify is not a JSON object, it's a jQuery-constructed object. It is a wrapper for the DOM elements jQuery finds. To make sure the select options are there you can do `console.dir( $('select[name="postalList"]').find('option') )`.

You can find an option by value `$('[value="yourOptionValueAttribute"]')`, just replace `yourOptionValueAttribute` with a value you get from `_d[postal].Id` . If you would add an id to your options, you could do `$('#yourOptionId')`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a perfectly accurate and concise answer, and worked perfectly.  Thanks!!